# Update classes and ressources of a Java Servlet when using Glassfish

Tags: java, servlets, deployment, intellij-idea

In IDEA IntelliJ I have the option to:

- Update resources
- Update classes and resources
- Redeploy
- Restart server

If I change some code of a Servlet then I always need to redeploy. Is there another way to "reload" faster to get changes affected?

Comment: Many ways. 1. Use spring-boot instead of glassfish. 2. Use a third-party tool like JRebel.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this IntelliJ WebHelp article: [Reloading Classes](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/reloading-classes.html)

However there are limitations:

> At the moment due to original limitations of Java SDK the **HotSwapping**
>   is possible ONLY if a method body is altered. In all other cases (like
>   changing method or class signature), the class reload is impossible
>   and the corresponding error message appears.

For more options you might want to check out what Engineer Dolly suggested in his comment to your question.